# Handle the selector parameter in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I declare a function in my CustomTimer class:

```
class CustomTimer {

    class func scheduledTimerWithSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> CustomTimer {
     // aSelector ??
    }
}
```

How can I handle this aSelector parameter?

Like the NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method, how dose it work?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it? Do you want to invoke it or pass further to other components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the `Selector` structure.
From the apple docs:

> In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by the Selector
>   structure. You can construct a selector with a string literal, such as
>   let mySelector: Selector = "tappedButton:". Because string literals
>   can be automatically converted to selectors, you can pass a string
>   literal to any method that accepts a selector.

Answer (score 1):

Selector function with Swift :

```
func selectorFunc(aSel:Selector){
    if self.respondsToSelector(aSel){
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: aSel, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func gooleIt(){
    println("Hello")
}
```

Function Call :

```
self.selectorFunc(Selector(gooleIt()))
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: thanks,  but i want to write a custom function with the selector parameter, not use a function with selector parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a method with a selector like this and you can call it by creating a UIControl because performSelector methods are not available in Swift:

```
func methodWithSelector(sel:Selector) {
        var control = UIControl()
        control.sendAction(sel, to: self, forEvent: nil)
}
```

If you do not need to call it on the main thread another option is like this:

```
func methodWithSelector(sel:Selector) {
    NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(sel, toTarget: self, withObject: nil)
}
```

You will call it like this:

```
methodWithSelector(Selector("methodCall"))
```

or like this

```
methodWithSelector("methodCall")
```

then you must have a method with the name of the selector

```
func methodCall() {
        println("methodCall")
    }
```